# bug de salida de pila en C++

Tags: c++

Tengo un menú para ingresar y sacar datos de una pila, la función de ingresar datos a la pila funciona correctamente, pero al intentar mostrar la salida de la misma no imprime nada, ni siquiera recorre el proceso para ver si la pila ya esta en NULL.

intenté hacer que la variable "valor" sea global pero los errores aumentan, la consola al ingresar la opción 2 solo muestra `***salida de la pila****` y se detiene el proceso y retorna al menú principal, tambien al compilar el visual me bota a otra ventana y me menciona un debug `wntdll.pdb not loaded`, pero no entiendo del todo de que se trata.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std; 


struct nodo {
    int dato;
    nodo* siguienteNodo;
};




void agregarPila(nodo *&prmPila,int prmValor) {
    nodo* nuevoNodo = new nodo();
    nuevoNodo->dato = prmValor;
    nuevoNodo->siguienteNodo = prmPila;
    prmPila = nuevoNodo;

    cout << "El dato se ha agregado exitosamente a la pila.\n";
}

void sacarPila(nodo *prmPila,int &prmValor) {

    nodo* aux = prmPila;
    prmValor = aux->dato;
    prmPila = aux->siguienteNodo;
    delete aux;
}

void salidaPila(int prmValor) {
    nodo* prmPila = NULL;
    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------------\n\tSALIDA DE LA PILA\n--------------------------------------------------------\n";
    while (prmPila!=NULL) {
        sacarPila(prmPila, prmValor);
        if (prmPila!=NULL) {
            cout << prmValor << " , ";
        }
        else {
            cout << prmValor << ".";
        }
    }
}

void imprimirMenu() {
    cout << "1. Ingresar pila.\n";
    cout << "2. Sacar pila.\n";
    cout << "3. Salir.\n";
    cout << "Seleccione una opcion:> ";
}

void menu() {
    nodo *pila=NULL;
    int valor;
    int varOpcion;
    do {
        imprimirMenu();
        cin >> varOpcion;
        switch (varOpcion)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------------\n\tINGRESANDO DATO A LA PILA\n--------------------------------------------------------\n";
            cout << "Ingrese un valor:> ";
            cin >> valor;
            agregarPila(pila,valor) ; break;
        case 2:
            salidaPila(valor); break;
        case 3:
            cout << "\n\tHa salido de la pila.\n"; break;
        default:
            cout << "La opcion ingresada no existe, Intente Nuevamente..."; break;
        }
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
    } while (varOpcion!=3);
}

int main()
{
    menu();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void salidaPila(int prmValor) {
    nodo* prmPila = NULL;
    while (prmPila!=NULL) {
```

En la segunda línea creas un puntero de tipo `nodo` que apunta a `0` y, en la siguiente, tienes un bucle que se repetirá mientras el puntero **no** sea nulo... es decir, el bucle no se va a ejecutar **jamás**

Si a todas las funciones les estás pasando un puntero o una referencia a la pila, esta función no debe ser una excepción:

```
void salidaPila(nodo* prmPila)
```

Aunque, como ya se ha comentado demasiadas veces en este foro, un nodo no es una pila, de la misma manera que una rueda no es un automovil.

Lo lógico es que tengas una clase `Pila`, que será la encargada de generar la estructura de nodos que corresponda... en este caso una pila LIFO. Este enfoque evita que expongas constantemente la estructura interna de la pila, lo que reduce significativamente los errores que puedas cometer al escribir el código.